# How has the teaching of (undergraduate) Set Theory changed over time?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-history

I'm writing an Essay on Set Theory, and realized it was formulated quite recently, so I thought it might be cool to have some first person accounts. Russell's Paradox was discovered just around a century ago. So I'm guessing that some of the senior members of this community might have experienced a tumult learning curriculum. Most of the undergraduate books in diverse areas offer an introduction to Set Theory in the first chapter, which is pretty standardized. Again, I'm speculating that it might not have been that way before. Other important events that might have impacted how set theory was teach would be Paul Cohen's discovery of forcing. 
So, reformulating my question, In your lifetime, have you seen a noticeable difference in how Set Theory is taught at an undergraduate level? If the question is too broad, please tell me so that I can modify it accordingly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Set theory is taught differently between universities, and even between professors. You may want to either contact specific people and ask them, or read a lot of historical essays (e.g. Kanamori's website is a good place to start).

Comment: You might look at when real analysis textbooks started including the now obligatory introductory chapter on set-theoretic preliminaries. I'm pretty sure they wouldn't have in Gauss's day. And what aspects of set theory they covered and how that may have changed over the years and why. Let us know what you find

Comment: @DanChristensen The only thing I could find by asking around, was that around the 80's, and maybe before, there was a boom in teaching Set Theory in Highschool.

Comment: Forget high schools. I would go back to university calculus textbooks for pure math starting in 1900. How were sets handled in undergrad courses before and after the advent of formal set theory around 1920?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the most basic "operational" topics, I don't think any standard for teaching set theory exists yet.

As soon as you starts really "doing set theory" things become non-trivial and not very accessible for undergrads. For weak evidence about this, here is my experience: when I was finishing my third year in my undergrad program (after measure theory and abstract algebra) we set with a classmate to read Halmos' Naive Set Theory. We gave up fairly soon, as it seemed impossible to follow for us. Then 27 years later I read it (last year), and it was so clear and easy to follow.

Comment: I was attempting to read Kunen's Set Theory, and couldn't understand much past the first few chapters. Do you think that "real set theory" needs a deeper understanding of formal logic? Or what do you think was the main difference between then, and last year that allowed you to read Halmos' book?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only difference is mathematical maturity. Now that you mention it,  Halmos' proofs are a little convoluted in their logic;  so it is not about formal logic per se, but about more practice in following mathematical reasoning.